# How to interpret the equation of a line in 3D through two points, when there are $0$s in the denominator?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d

If $A=(0,0,0)$ and $B=(1,0,0)$ are two points of a line in three dimensions, I think its equation should be
$$\frac{x-0}{1}=\frac{y-0}{0}=\frac{z-0}{0}\tag1$$
according to the formula 
$$\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{y-y_1}{y_2-y_1}=\frac{z-z_1}{z_2-z_1}\tag2$$

But (1) has zeros in the denominator. How to interpret the relation between $x$,$y$ and $z$ then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer in general.. "how to find the equation of a line in $3$D given its two endpoints?". Let $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ two points. The line you're looking for is: $${\bf X}(t) = (x_0,y_0,z_0)+t(x_1-x_0,y_1-y_0,z_1-z_0), \quad t \in \Bbb R.$$ If you just want the segment, consider only $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Notice that ${\bf X}(0) = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and ${\bf X}(1) = (x_1,y_1,z_1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation doesn't quite work, since it has division by $0$. This is somewhat of an issue. However, think about it logically: $(0,0,0)$ is the origin and $(1,0,0)$ is some point on the $x$-axis. Hey, those are two points on the $x$-axis, which is a line, and hence is the unique line between them. The $x$-axis is clearly defined by
$$y=z=0$$
and no constraint is placed on $x$.

We can (informally) read your equation two ways - first, we could "multiply" out by $0$ and cancel with the denominators - which yields $0=y=z$. We could also think that the numerators of $\frac{y-0}0$ and $\frac{z-0}0$ better be $0$, since at least that gives us the indeterminate form $\frac{0}0$ instead of the clearly wrong $\frac{1}0$ or something like that. These aren't super formal ways of thinking about it (but they *can* be formalized with limits), but they'll yield the right answer when used carefully.